# XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()

Tags: angularjs, csv, angular

i am trying to set parameters for XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()in order to be able to import csv files. Although, i am sure it's able to identity the token of the user logged in, i get an error when i submit the csv or xlxs file. What could be wrong?

```
//file service
   public progress$;
   public progressObserver;
   public progress : number;
   public headers:string;


    constructor (private auth:AuthenticationService) {
        this.progress$ = Observable.create(observer => {
            this.progressObserver = observer
        }).share();
    }

     makeFileRequest (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]) {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {

                this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100)
                this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
            };


            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader(this.headers, this.auth.token);
            xhr.send(formData);


        });
    }
}
//Exception

ErrorHandler</ErrorHandler.prototype.handleError http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44671:9
    PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone/</<.next http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:29085:65
    EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30598:36
    SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:632:13
    SafeSubscriber</SafeSubscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:581:17
    Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype._next http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:534:9
    Subscriber</Subscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:498:13
    Subject</Subject.prototype.next http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:3046:17
    EventEmitter</EventEmitter.prototype.emit http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:30590:54
    NgZone</NgZone.prototype.triggerError http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:31404:56
    NgZone</NgZone.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onHandleError http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:31383:17
    Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.handleError http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:102771:17
    Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:102692:25
    ZoneTask/this.invoke http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:102870:28
```

//error

```
onChange
file.ts:27 FileList {0: File, length: 1}
:4200/#/dashboard/customer:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/v1/file/food. Request header field undefined is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: 
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
next @ application_ref.js:272
schedulerFn @ async.js:82
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught 
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:227
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:236
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:157
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
file.ts:20 progress = NaN
```

Comment: Is there any other error information? All I see in your error text is that an error was handled, but is there any error info? Something from debug window, console, stack trace? Where exactly does the error occur (in your observers, etc?)?

Comment: @TimConsolazio, i have updated the error in the console

Comment: Seems you have CORS problem. You need add all used headers into `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` on your server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in this line

```
xhr.setRequestHeader(this.headers, this.auth.token);
```

In your code you have not assigned anything to `this.headers` so that will end up adding an header named `undefined` which your server will not understand.

Below is a sample of how you should be doing it. As VadimB mentioned you will still have to add your custom header to the cors config in your server `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

```
// Make sure this.auth.token is assigned your token
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', this.auth.token);

// sending jwt in most scenarios
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer xxx.xxx.xxx');
```

Please read the documentation on xhr to understand what is used where and when.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest